# How to publish terraform provider as official terraform module?

Tags: terraform

I have written a basic custom terraform provider for our company using this guide https://www.terraform.io/guides/writing-custom-terraform-providers.html.

Now as a next step, I want to publish it as official terraform module, like other official providers available at https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/index.html.

I couldn't find any documentation on this. Can someone explain steps to publish a custom terraform provider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several choices.

First you need open source it and name the repository as below format:

```
github.com/<your_account>/terraform-provider-<provider_name>
```

So others can start using your provider, if it is useful. Give the detail instruction in `README.md` on how to use it. You also need set auto build processes (by free CI tool, such as travis ci, circle ci, codeship, etc), build into binary file and release it with different version and operation systems regularly.

You can refer the exist terraform provider's `.travis.yml` on how to release it. For example:

https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/master/.travis.yml

If you DO think your provider is useful, and important for open source community, contact Hashicorpy directly to ask them to add your provider to the organisation: https://github.com/terraform-providers

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. I have already uploaded my provider on github https://github.com/AviatrixSystems/terraform-provider-aviatrix. I still need to set travis. I have also contacted hashicorp for more information.

Comment: congrats! and thanks for asking this in case i ever want to make one. Starred.